# Astable multivibrator inverter

Tags: oscillator, efficiency, multivibrator, astable

I'm new to electronics and trying to make an astable multivibrator oscillator. The PSpice simulation doesn't work (it says netlist error when I place a mosfet or a diode) and I get a really low efficiency (like around 10% on falstad.com). Is there anyway I can improve the design?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post to include the picture, rather than giving a link -- not only is it inconvenient to go to the link, but we can't trust outside sites not to take pictures down.  Better yet, use the schematic editor here (which should also simulate).  Please also include part numbers.  I suspect that at least one problem is not providing sufficient gate drive -- a generic power MOSFET would need 10V.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the image. The simulator I used (falstad, PSpice isn't working) only offers a generic mosfet component. I'll try increasing the gate voltage to see what happens.

Comment: Check the mosfets ,if they are real there will not be enough gate volts to turn them on properly